# bootstrap css not loading in django template

Tags: python, css, django, bootstrap-4

when loading base_html all bootstrap css is loading:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "artdb/css/custom.css" %}">
```

but when I want to load my signin page no css is loaded:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Custom styles for this template -->
<link hrel="stylesheet" href="{% static "artdb/css/signin.css" %}">
```

my urls.py:

```
path('',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='artdb/base.html')),
path('signin/',TemplateView.as_view(template_name='artdb/signin.html')),
```

any ideas?

I have {% load staticfiles %} in both files. Any ideas?

Comment: it should be is `{% load static %}` not `{% load staticfiles %}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your sigin page change the custom style reference from `hrel` to `rel`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "artdb/css/signin.css" %}">
```